# In Windows 10, is there are way to run a specific task either at a certain time or at the time of log-on?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I have registered the following task task to run at 7am:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name SystemUsesLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force; New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize -Name AppsUseLightTheme -Value 1 -Type Dword -Force
```

The purpose is to switch from dark to light theme in Windows (and in all other apps like Office or Thunderbird that take their cue from the Windows theme).

At 8pm I run a similar command to switch the theme from light to dark.

For both I also ticked the boxes to "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed", e.g.., for when the PC is asleep.

**Now my issue**: Most of the time, this works, but sometimes it does not and I don't understand why. Is there an internal time limit for the option "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"? E.g., if the task is missed by more than X hours it will not run?

Second question: can these tasks be implemented using a combination of run "On a schedule" and "At log on"? In the UI you have to choose either/or but maybe this can be done using a command line? Specifically I would like to do: Run task at 7am OR if log on occurs before 8pm. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I think I now understand why it fails sometimes: it happens if both tasks are missed. Say it misses the switch to dark mode in the evening and then also misses the switch to light mode in the next morning, then, when I wake the PC, both tasks are executed and it seems that the switch to dark mode task is executed last, so the PC remains in dark mode although it is maybe midday. So I guess, what I should really ask is, can I prevent a task from being executed if the start is missed by more than X hours. I know this can be done by repeating the task for X hours but this seems inefficient. Thanks